# Firebase App Distribution APK will not install

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-app-distribution

I'm using the Firebase App distribution to send out updates to a few testers and the most recent APK I uploaded will not install on Android devices (actually it is several new versions that all have issues installing). I had previously uploaded a version that worked, but all subsequent updates fail with an 'App not installed' error message. I'm confused by the APK files that are generated from Android Studio and I don't recall which version I previously uploaded that worked. In the apk folder there is a debug folder that contains an apk file named app-debug.apk. I'm pretty sure this is the one I used with the successful version of the distribution. There is also a flutter-apk folder with an identically named file app-debug.apk. Does anyone know the difference between these files and which one I should use? That question is a side note as neither of those files work.

I have tried telling my testers to uninstall the previous (working) version and then try to update their Android with the latest version, but the error still occurs. I do not have any issues with my iOS version and that test group.

Do I need to update the debug.keystore file? I have searched many different threads for a solution and nothing seems to work. Any suggestions to debug the issue would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, if the package exported by debug cannot be installed on some devices, such as "parsing failure", you can add a signature file to the debug version. It is better to generate it yourself, and do not use the tool's own. In addition, you can add a signature file to the debug version androidmanifast.xml  Statement under application android:testOnly= "False", which may help you

Comment: Thanks, I will try that to see if it helps

Comment: Unfortunately, adding the android:testOnly="False" statement did not correct the problem.